# PayPal Mobile SDK payment verification

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing server side payment verification on parse cloud code and so far it all works.

My question is with reference to the documentation -> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Can I just implement the 'Looking up a payment using the REST API' for verification section or do i have to also do further requests and implement the 'How do I verify payments with MSDK version 1.x' sections as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may skip the section of "verify payments with MSDK version 1.x", unless you've integrated with the old version 1.x mobile SDK.

*1.x msdk implements PayPal account payments with "Adaptive Payments" so the verification has to be slightly different from 2.x